# Conway exercise 5

Tags: complex-analysis

Lef $f$ be analytic on $\overline{B}(0,R)$ with $|f(z)|\leq M$ for $|z|\leq R$ y $|f(0)|=a>0$. Show that the number of zeros of $f$ in $B(0;R/3)$ is less than or equal to
$$\frac{\log(M/a)}{\log2}.$$

(Hint: If $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ are the zeros of $f$ in $B(0;R/3)$, consider the function
$$g(z)=f(z)\left[\prod_{k=1}^n \left(1-\frac{z}{z_k}\right)\right]^{-1}$$
and note that $g(0)=f(0)$)
It is in the section of The maximum modulus theorem (mmt), so I must use that theorem.

My idea: I think that since $g$ is holomorphic and doesnt have zeros in $B(0;R/3)$ then
$$g(z)=e^{s(z)}$$
with $s(z)$ holomorphic in $B(0;R/3)$. Then I don't know how to relate it with the zeros of $f$. Any suggestions? I think the theorem of Rouche may help, but I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with a tighter bound using Jensen's formula, I think. But using just the maximum modulus principle, you can argue as follows: evidently $g$ is analytic on $\overline{B(0,R)}$. For $\vert z\vert=R$, note that $\vert z/z_k\vert\geq 3$. What does this mean for each factor in $g$, and therefore for how large $\vert g(z)\vert$ could possibly be when $\vert z\vert=R$? You should find this depends on the number of roots, $n$. On the other hand, you know that $\vert g(0)\vert = a$. Where does the maximum modulus principle come in now to give you your bound on $n$?

Comment: Thanks, now I understand it.